# How to display images from a variable in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am displaying images in my react native app.

Here is how I am displaying the image:

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: this.props.img }}
```

My image is not displayed, but when I put the url directly into the image I works fine

What is happening

Comment: your prop contains img?

Comment: Yup I checked... I the props has the url but doesn't display the image but when I insert the image directly as a string it works

Comment: apply a check and then render the image component if this.props.img != "" ? { render your component} : null

Comment: Please try to add height and width to the image, if you have not added it now.
    <Image
      style={{
        height: 94,
        width: 132
      }}
      source={{ uri: this.props.img }}
    ></Image>

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put `this` in elements, please remove it before props and use directly as below

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: props.img }}
```

Comment: I am not using the class approach and therefore I have used this.props.imag

Comment: @xifir, if you are not using the class based approach, then you should not be using `this.props`, but `props` (which you'll receive as an parameter in your functional component).

Comment: @xifir If you are not using class component then you shouldn't use `this`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, if there is an image in your props that you've passed. `console.log` that prop.

Also, add `this` keyword only when you're using the class approach.